# ImageResizer rotates images

Tags: asp.net-mvc, imageresizer

I use [ImageResizer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ImageResizer) in my web application. It resizes most of the images on the page correctly. But there is one set of images, that it rotates. The code is the same for all the images.

See the following [link](http://www.search2stay.com/ListingImageUploads/18/twin%202.jpg?width=500), if you remove the querystring for ?width=500, then the image is right, but the width, resizes the image and rotates it for some reason

Please any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Cameras do not rotate images according to the orientation sensor; they just set a flag in the metadata.

Install the [AutoRotate plugin](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/autorotate) and put &autorotate=true in the querystring. This will cause the image to be rotated according to the metadata prior to any rotate commands.

Answer (score 0):

When I downloaded the images they were upside down, I fixed this paint.net, re-uploaded, now they are fine. The funny thing is when viewing the image in browser without the querystring they were fine.Wierd...